# How to change theme background color and text color on selection

Tags: css, angularjs

Is there any way to change the style of the web page on by user selection using CSS in angular js.

I tried in google but nothing is working for me.

I have a CSS file which will have style. I need to rewrite the style in all divs wherever needed by changing the background colour, text colour, font style.

```
    $scope.model.webPageSkin = 'Default';  

    // create the list of themes  
    $scope.bootstraps = [  
        { name: 'Plain', url: 'Plain' },  
        { name: 'Blue', url: 'Blue' },  
        { name: 'Green', url: 'Green' } , 
        { name: 'Default', url: 'default' } , 
    ]; 

**Plain.css**

ChangeColor  
{  
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Calibri,Candara,Arial,sans-serif;  
    font-size: 15px;  
    line-height: 1.42857143;  
    color: #333333;  
    background-color: #ddd;  
}  


**default.css**

.ChangeColor  
{  
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Calibri,Candara,Arial,sans-serif;  
    font-size: 15px;  
    line-height: 1.42857143;  
    color: #333333;  
    background-color: #3c8dbc;  
}  

<div class="wrapper>
     <header class="main-header">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" ng-class="{ChangeColor: 
           model.webPageSkin !important;}">
          </nav>
     </header>

<div class="row">
<select  ng-model="model.webPageSkin" ng-options="bootstrap.url as bootstrap.name for bootstrap in bootstraps">  
                </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-class takes an angularjs expression to evaluate, not the CSS styling you're currently specifying.

[ngClass API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

So your markup needs to change to basically say, I want the css class of 'ChangeColor' whenever angular evalutes model.webPageSkin to be truthy.

```
ng-class="{'ChangeColor': model.webPageSkin}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code like this:

```
ng-class="{'ChangeColor': model.webPageSkin==='Default'}">
```

`ng-class` only works for `true` and `false` if there is `true` value the `class` will be applied

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*----Plain.css---*/

body{
 background-color:grey;
}


/*----Blue.css-----*/

body{
 background-color:blue;
}

/*------Default.css------*/

body{
 background-color:cyan;
}

/*-----Green.css----*/

body{
 background-color:green;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script >
            var app=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
            app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){ 
                 $scope.webPageSkin="Default"; 
          console.log($scope.webPageSkin);

    $scope.bootstraps = [  
        { name: 'Plain', url: 'Plain.css' },  
        { name: 'Blue', url: 'Blue.css' },  
        { name: 'Green', url: 'Green.css' } , 
        { name: 'Default', url: 'Default.css' } , 
    ]; 

            });
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="wrapper">
        
     <header class="main-header" ng-class="webPageSkin.name">
          <nav  class="navbar navbar-static-top">
          </nav>
     </header>

<div class="row">
<select ng-model="webPageSkin" ng-options="bootstrap.name for bootstrap in bootstraps" ng-init="webPageSkin = bootstraps[0]">
                </select>       
</div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="{{webPageSkin.url}}">
    </body>
</html>
```

Create four css file by the same name and also can edit as per the requirement.Now it is completed.

Comment: Ur implementation is related with ng-class though u r asking to change css files,the above code snippet changes the css file on selection of select element,it dynamically changes the href for style sheet.